Rotating the Drawview kotlin component in compose disables the onTouchCallbacks
I am trying to rotate the Composable component using Modifier.rotate.But this disables the touch events from my drawview handler?
Here is the code used :
My DrawView Code (In Kotlin):
   
class DrawView : View {
    companion object {
        const val DEBUG_LOG = "DrawViewLogs"
        const val WHITE_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 24F
        const val BLUE_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 20F
        const val ANIMATION_DURATION: Long = 200
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

    }



    //  DrawView class programmatically in code
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        isFocusable = true // necessary for getting the touch events
//        setMeasuredDimension(2250,4000)
    }

    //constructor for DrawView in an XML layout file
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyle
    ) {
        isFocusable = true // necessary for getting the touch events
    }

    //constructor for DrawView in an XML layout file but without any style params passed in xml
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        isFocusable = true // necessary for getting the touch events
    }

    private var linePaint = Paint().also { paint ->
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        paint.isDither = true
        paint.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)
        paint.strokeWidth = 8f
    }

    // the method that draws on canvas
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_LOG, "$width $height")
        //draw the corners
        for (i in points.indices) {
            if (i + 1 == points.size) {
                if (isShowCropRect) {
                    canvas.drawLine(
                        points[i].x,
                        points[i].y,
                        points[0].x,
                        points[0].y,
                        linePaint
                    )
                }
                canvas.drawCircle(points[i].x, points[i].y, WHITE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, whitePaint)
                canvas.drawCircle(points[i].x, points[i].y, BLUE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, bluePaint)
                canvas.drawCircle(points[0].x, points[0].y, WHITE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, whitePaint)
                canvas.drawCircle(points[0].x, points[0].y, BLUE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, bluePaint)
            } else {
                if (isShowCropRect) {
                    canvas.drawLine(
                        points[i].x,
                        points[i].y,
                        points[i + 1].x,
                        points[i + 1].y,
                        linePaint
                    )
                }
                if (i != 0) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(points[i].x, points[i].y, WHITE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, whitePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(points[i].x, points[i].y, BLUE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, bluePaint)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // events when touching the screen
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
      
        val localPosition = PointF(event.x, event.y)
        when (event.action) {
            
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {

                  
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                                }
             
            }
        }

        return true
    }

}

Compose Code to use and rotate the view when angle changes:
   val drawView = remember {
        DrawView(context)
    }
 AndroidView(
        factory = {
            drawView.apply {
                initializeForCameraScreen()
                resetCornerPoints()
            }
        },

        modifier = Modifier
            .rotate(rotation_angle)
            .fillMaxSize()

When rotated ,onTouchEvent stops getting called when moving finger over the canvas.
Why this is happening?
